How to programmatically reroute a phone number on Twilio on a different region, using the API
I want to understand how to change the voice configuration of a number in another region and how to reroute it using the api.
Basically, it means performing the actions available on this screen, via the API. (Going to other configuration region and change the value of the webhook url)
The twilio interface
I tried this, but it change the only US configuration.
const clientEU = new Twilio(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN, {region: "ie1"});
const res = await clientEU.incomingPhoneNumbers("PID").update({
   voiceUrl: "https://test.com",
});

EDIT
I found the way to route the Voice url to the desired region, but I am unable to edit the voice url in this region.
const res = await clientEU.routes.v2
    .phoneNumbers("phoneNumber")
    .update({ voiceRegion: "ie1" });


Did you find a solution to change the voice url (= webhook) in UE1 region ? Thanks.
